# Can System.Net.WebClient be used in a console app to stream what my HttpHandler can do with Httpcontext.Response.OutputStream.Write?

Tags: console-application, webclient, httpresponse

I'm trying to do something in a console app for a test (based on some code in an HttpHandler in a web app).

Given something like **this below** which works for my HttpHandler which has HttpContext passed to it:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", docContent.Length.ToString());
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
context.Response.ContentType = MIMEType.MimeType(fileType);
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(docContent, 0, docContent.Length);
context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

I have part of it, I think and then I get stuck:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();

client.Headers.Add("Content-Length", docContent.Length.ToString());
client.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
string ContentType = MIMEType.MimeType(fileType);
// ??
// how to build the response as an output stream from my byte array which has the data ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MemoryStream(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) can create a `Stream` from a `byte[]`.

But a problem is `WebClient` is designed to issue HTTP *requests* only. If your goal is to test the server by downloading an attachment, then you'll need different headers.

If indeed you're trying to download a file, then try using [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)